# CSS fixed position not working on sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, animation, sass

I am working on fixed right sidebar with toggle button. The toggle button is `position: fixed` and `top: 10px`. So the button will fixed on top when user scroll down the page content. The problem is when user click the toggle button on the middle (or the end) of page content. The sidebar content only show the background without sidebar items (User need to scroll to top to view the sidebar item). I want to show the whole sidebar items whenever user click the toggle button

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tjog7sp2/5/)

Sidebar working properly on the top of content:
[image: Sidebar]

Not working in the middle of page content:
[image: Fixed toggle on the middle content]

[image: Only background color withou sidebar items]

Answer (score 0):

Your current layout is created in a way that the only way your will be able to set sidebar content fixed is with additional JS libraries.

I suggest to edit and recreate it using this example: https://www.cssscript.com/sliding-push-navigation-menu-pure-css/

Here is the live demo:

```css
/* -- Slideout Sidebar -- */

.slideout-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -190px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #212121;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}


/* -- Slideout Sidebar -- */

.slideout-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -190px;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #212121;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.slideout-sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideout-sidebar ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.4);
  color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.7);
}

.slideout-sidebar ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.slideout-sidebar ul li:hover {
  color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 1);
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}


/*-- The Magic --*/

#menu-toggle:checked~.slideout-sidebar {
  left: 0px;
}

#menu-toggle:checked+.menu-icon {
  left: 210px;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~.content-container {
  padding-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox">

<label for="menu-toggle" class="menu-icon">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</label>

<div class="content-container">
  <div class="site-title">
    <h1>Push Navigation</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/720/250/people" alt="" class="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget nulla mollis, efficitur urna nec, viverra dolor. Nulla facilisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
      luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent efficitur finibus eros sit amet sagittis. Ut sollicitudin sodales neque et volutpat. Curabitur dictum ante vel fermentum volutpat. Curabitur ac neque et erat viverra egestas.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slideout-sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> About Us</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Blog</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following css for your side bar. You'll need to make the .side-bar position fixed and you also need to remove the transform property as it affects the position: fixed property.

```
.side-nav{ 
 height: 100%;
 width: $side-nav-width;
 position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #253781;
//transform: translateX(-$side-nav-width); 
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 20px;}
```